# Open Spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

In my android application I am using Spinner.It is working fine.

But I want to show my spinner in different style as per [mentioned link](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/components-menus-menus-textfield_dropdown_spec_large_xhdpi.webm)

Kindly provide me solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you can use a 3rd party library I will recommend you to use this one. I used it and it's working fine.

https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner

Inside the repo are the steps to use it.